# "In and of itself"? What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

"It might be different if he were flagging down a passing car or trying to phone for help, but typing, in and of itself, is not an inherently dramatic activity."

In this sentence, I do not understand the phrase "in and of itself"  There should be some difference between the prepositions "in" and "of" in this context.

Please explain in as much detail as possible!

Comment: It's the same as *per se*. How's that for an explanation? :)

Comment: Hi Huidong! [Did you look up this phrase in a dictionary?](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+and+of+itself) I know that most people think that dictionaries are only for words, not for phrases, but actually, many modern (read: online) dictionaries include phrases, idioms, and other multi-word structures. If you *have* looked it up and you're still having trouble understanding it, you need to explicitly say so in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you are just considering the object narrowly, without including consideration of its connections with other things or regarding it in context.

If you starting taking context and relations to other things into account, then the statement that was qualified by *in and of itself* might no longer be true (without that qualification).

IOW, it means abstracting from relations to other things, or looking at the thing narrowly, considering only its intrinsic nature, not also its external relations.

Answer (score -1):

The phrase of concern is

> Typing in and of itself is not an inherently dramatic activity.

This phrase can be defactorized into two separate phrases

1. Typing in itself is not an inherently dramatic activity.
2. Typing of itself is not an inherently dramatic activity.

To demonstrate the meaning of *in itself*

> Typing a romantic story on the editor is very tantalizing and emotionally arousing, but typing **in itself** is not an inherently dramatic activity. I don't like typing. I wish there is a computer which could read my mind.

To demonstrate the meaning of *of itself*

> Typing a political suspense is very involved. I need to do a huge amount of research and ensure my invented histories are coherent with actual history. However, **of the typing itself**, there is nothing to research on nor any improvement needed, unless I were a novice one-finger typist, which I am not.